# fixed button with animation on middle right side of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to create a button like the one you see [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/)

This page has a `Feedback` button on the right hand side which is near to the scrollbar. How can I create a similar button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a lot of solutions depending on the exact behaviour you want with the feedback button. Those can involve JavaScript to delay the button's appearance, and CSS transforms to rotate the element. The simplest one, I think, would be to create a `fixed` element and setting it's `right` to `0`.

```css
.feedback {
   position: fixed;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 30%;
   height: 80px;
   width: 20px;

   background-color: #55E;
   color: #FFF;
}

.feedback:hover {
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback">
</div>
```